# Default value for uninitialized hash key

Tags: perl, c#-2.0

Like in Perl, if a hash key is uninitialized then if you perform the below code

```
$hash{$key} =~ $hash{$key}++
```

then the value for that particular key increases to 1 (cause, it's first undefined and then as per the context, here it's numaical ... it takes the value to 0 ... increases it to 1).

My question is, does the same concept follows in case of C# as well? I mean, if I perform the above code in c# what would be the result? Will it be 1 or what?

Any idea?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: That is a bizarre and convoluted way to see if a hash has a certain key.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That bit of code makes no sense.

If you want to know if the key exists in the hash:

```
if (exists $hash{$key}) { ... }
```

If you want to know if it has a value defined:

```
if (defined $hash{$key}) { ... }
```

If you want to increment the value,

$hash{$key}++

As it is, you're attempting to do a regex match in a rather nonsensical way.

Comment: It's not nonsensical; it's both incrementing and testing if it was previously defined (because postincrement returns 0 when its argument is undef, and undef=~0 will be false).  But it's extremely obfuscated.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong; the string matched against is the value after the increment, so this is undef=~0 or 2=~1 or 3=~2 etc and will never match.

Comment: @ysth/@David, yes, correct that ... it's not the way at all to check whether a hash key exist or not and neither it's my code ... I found that in someone else code and had to perform something same in C# ... Also, apart from nonsensical/obfuscated ... it's confusing too :)

Answer (score 0):

OOPS!!! Sorry ... I got it; actually the Perl code mentioned is meant to check/confirm whether the particular "KEY" exist or not ... OR sort of that.

So, in C# I cna just check for "hashtable.containskey(key)" ... that will do the trick.

Thanks.

Comment: Close, what the above code *actually* did was check to see if the original value was defined. It's possible to have a key that both exists, and is undefined.